# how to cfloop query the line if there is only 1 column

Tags: coldfusion, vertica

this is my sql query

```
`CONST_SQL_clean="
    select    table_name from  tables where  TABLE_NAME  not in ('TBL_SY', 'TBL_USER')

        ";`
```

i want to modify the result and execute it as new query for every table name selected by this query

```
<cffunction name="clean_data" access="remote" returntype="struct" >


    <cfscript>
            lSqlManager = createObject("component","#request.stMapping.strCFC#.sqlManager");
            lSqlManager.setSqlString(CONST_SQL_select);                      

    </cfscript> 


      <CFQUERY NAME="qResult" DATASOURCE="#request.stMapping.strODBCName#">
            #lSqlManager.getSqlString()#
      </CFQUERY>

      <cfloop query="qResult">
      <cfset str= "delete" & #qResult# >
      QueryExecute  (str);
      </cfloop>
    <cfscript>
     return qResult;
    </cfscript>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify this.  It will be much easier.

First, get the tables you want to empty.

```
<cfquery name = "tablesToClear">
select table_name
from tables
where table_name not in ('TBL_SY', 'TBL_USER')
</cfquery>
```

Now create your loop and delete your rows.

```
<cfoutput query = "tablesToClear">
<cfquery>
delete from #table_name#
</cfquery>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Dear sir thanks for your response but  when i put it in the cfloop it tell me there is an error this is how i put it
 <cfloop query="qResult">
             <cfquery>
          delete from #table_name#
               </cfquery>
          </cfloop>

Comment: That's because you are using cfloop instead of cfoutput to create the loop.  If you want to do that, you still need the cfoutput tag outside the loop.

Comment: @spinxking Depending on how big those tables are, you might be better off `TRUNCATING` the tables instead of `DELETE`. It really depends on your ultimate goals. Though I think `TRUNCATE` behaves slightly differently in Vertica vs SQL Server. If you're trying to completely "reset" a table, `TRUNCATING` may be better. I still recommend using a bulk statement rather than looping over a query (if possible here).